# How do I show the count of a specific group of metrics from a prometheus histogram?

Tags: prometheus

So, I have a histogram that collects duration in seconds for some operations, metrics are:

- rpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket
- rpc_request_duration_seconds_count
- rpc_request_duration_seconds_sum

And this works, I get my quantiles and all, but I want to get a count of all requests that go over 1 second. How do I produce a query like that?

Answer (score 6):

```
rate(rpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="+Inf"}[1m]) 
  - ignoring(le)
rate(rpc_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="1.0"}[1m])
```

will return how many queries are going over 1s every second.

This is all queries, minus the queries that take less than or equal to one second.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write something like

```
rate(rpc_request_duration_seconds_count [1m])
```

This will give you the requests per second in a (sliding) interval of 1 minute. See the [Query functions](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#rate()) doc of Prometheus.